# Anaconda Python : cannot execute native linux-64 binary on a 64 bit machine

Tags: python, linux, anaconda

I'm trying to install Anaconda on my Toshiba Chromebook, and am running into the following error :

```
cannot execute native linux-64 binary, output from 'uname -a' is:
Linux localhost 3.14.0 #1 SMP PREEMPT Wed Jul 20 21:06:48 PDT 2016 x86_64 Intel(R) Celeron(R) CPU 3215U @ 1.70GHz GenuineIntel GNU/Linux
```

here is a screenshot of the error
[image: here is a screenshot of the error]

any idea what's causing this error?

Comment: Your `CPU_Thread_Count >= MAX_CPU_THREAD` Try: `kill desktop > connect via ssh > install your app` . You got a `**WEAK**` CPU on thread.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion . I managed to install it by changing the download location to /usr/local .

Comment: @WitchKingofAngmar - I don't see how that can solve the problem (though I'm no expert on alpine). I just tested putting both the miniconda installer, and my installation target in /usr/local and saw no change in behaviour.

Comment: In addition, getting the 32 bit installer also makes no difference. There are miniconda alpine docker images out there - the Dockerfiles are insightful: https://github.com/CognitiveScale/alpine-miniconda/blob/master/Dockerfile

Comment: Just a guess but this might be a problem with the Anaconda install script. It's trying to parse the output of `uname -a` to look for an indication of 64-bit architecture. My next best guess is that the `#` in the output (e.g. "#1") is creating a comment in the way they are parsing that output, perhaps through a subshell or something, which is only seeing `"Linux localhost 3.14.0 "` and therefore can't verify you're on a 64-bit system.